# Problem: Sidewaysfigure automatically start a new page

Tags: diagrams, rotating

Basically, I have a blank page, I inserted the subsection title and underneath I want to add a sideways figure.

```
\subsection{Findings}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.2]{hi.pdf}
\captionof{figure}{picture1} 
\label{123}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

However, the problem is that I managed to get subsection title printed on one page, but the sideways figure is always on the another page. Is it possible make them appear on the same page ?

Comment: Please always post _complete_ small document that shows the problem It's impossible to say much from a fragment as above, float placement depends on many factors, most of which are impossible to guess given a fragment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, this is a `sidewaysfigure`, which always is placed on a separate page, so not really the normal float placement issue.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. a sideways figure is a normal float (with `\rotatebox` implictly applied to the content, it shouldn't start a new page normally. (but will default to t or p of course, not h)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Hmm actually rotating makes the box textheight tall so it is a normal float but will never fit `h` so you're right that the end result is that it never ends up on the current page

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see, thanks for the correction. (I should know better than to argue with you ...)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. well from a user perspective your comment was more helpful than mine:-)

Comment: I have a felling I may have suggested `rotating` instead of `lscape` in an earlier question. Sorry I mislead you, the link in @TorbjørnT.'s comment above has working code.